# Group by equidistant integer intervals

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, timescaledb

I am using [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/) (an extension to [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)) to store altitude data from a GPS sensor. The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS altitude 
(
  time              TIMESTAMPTZ      NOT NULL,
  workout_id        VARCHAR(24)      NOT NULL,
  user_id           VARCHAR(24)      NOT NULL,
  altitude          DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  gain              DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  loss              DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  activity_type     VARCHAR(32)      NOT NULL,
  elapsed_distance  DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  absolute_distance DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  elapsed_time      DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  absolute_time     DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);
```

- **altitude** This is the geographical altitude at the point the altitude point was recorded.
- **absolute_time** This is the absolute time since the start of the recording
- **absolute_distance** This is the absolute distance traveled since the start of the recording
- **elapsed_distance** This is the elapsed distance between two successive altitude points
- **elapsed_time** This is the elapsed time between two successive altitude points
- **gain** The altitude gain between two successive altitude points
- **loss** The altitude loss between two successive altitude points

I want to calculate the speed by distance, that is I want something like:

```
SELECT distance, speed FROM calculate_speed_by_distance(from_time, to_time, step_distance) ORDER BY distance
```

The **step** should specify the distance interval the resulting speed should be calculated beginning at the distance already traveled at **from_time** to the distance traveled at **to_time**. 
E.g. **speed=200** (with a distance at **from_time** of 0m and a distance of **to_time** of 756m) sould mean:

```
0m     200m     400m     600m     800m
0km/h  5km/h    10km/h   11km/h   8km/h
```

The speed (**absolute_distance/absolute_time**) should be averaged among all successive altitude points in each interval.

If there are no altitude points in some intervals, the last calculated speed point can be used.

So I need something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_speed_by_distance(arg_time_from timestamp,
                                                 arg_time_to timestamp,
                                                 arg_distance_step bigint,
                                                 arg_workout_id varchar(24),
                                                 arg_user_id varchar(24))
    RETURNS TABLE
            (
                distance double precision,
                value    double precision
            )
AS
'
    BEGIN
        RETURN query with ...
    END;
' LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

**So the question is**: How to aggregate the data in the current format to calculate the speed by distance in the aforementioned way?

EDIT:

Example data for **altitude points**: See [here](https://hackmd.io/s/HJ2v402ZH)

Best,

Philipp

Comment: Can you clarify what is your question? What is your particular difficulty?

Comment: I have added the actual question, thanks. The difficulty comes from the kind the data needs to be aggregated - not by time but by a custom integer range. TimescaleDB offers only time_bucket_gapfill to do time bucketed aggregation.

Comment: Can you explain how step-distance relates to absolute-distance in OP? My understanding is that it might aggregate, but might split absolute-distance. May be example with data will help to understand.

Comment: I have added more information and example data. I can also add elapsed-distance and elapsed-time (between two successive altitude points) in the dataset if this is easier for the calculation.

Comment: Thank you for adding the example. Now it is much more clear about the data granularity and that aggregating is necessary.

Comment: I don't think it is reasonable to do as a single SQL query, since it will be very nested, will be expensive to execute, and unlikely to utilise optimisations of TimescaleDB. Instead use SQL procedural constructions such as cursor and local variables. It should be straightforward to write.